# SMS Message text is incorrect

Tags: civisms

I am using the Twilio extension to send SMS Messages from within CiviCRM. The text above the textbox states 'You can insert up to 460 characters'. This is incorrect and should read 'You can insert up to 160 characters'. I am not sure where to change the text. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be most grateful.

Comment: Just ran into this one too.  It seems that Clickatell supports up to 460 characters by segmenting the message - as do most mobile phone companies.  But Twilio doesn't through the Civi extension? - but see this https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181508-Does-Twilio-support-concatenated-SMS-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters-

Answer (score 1):

Maximum SMS length is defined by the `MAX_SMS_CHAR` constant in

`../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/SMS/Provider.php`.